# Cannot resolve symbol `PRIORITY_HIGH`

Tags: android, android-studio, android-5.0-lollipop, android-notification-bar

I was trying to show a heads-up notification but android studio simply can't recognize the symbol `PRIORITY_HIGH`.

Here is the code:

```
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(context1,MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context1,0, intent1,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context1);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context1.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setContentTitle("MOODS")
                .setContentIntent(pendingNotificationIntent)
                .setContentText("Quote:\t"+quote+"\nAuthor:\t" +author)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, you need to be more specific with the errors you are facing. It'd be better to post a build log (Run build and the paste the log errors here).

Comment: You are using `NotificationCompat`. Use `NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH` as well.

Comment: oh it worked. tnx!

Answer (score 0):

[`DEFAULT_ALL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#DEFAULT_ALL) has existed since API version 1, whereas

[`PRIORITY_HIGH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#PRIORITY_HIGH) was introduced with API version 16.

It is my assumption that your API level is set to something between these two.

Seeing as you are using the *compat* library, you should also use the flags from there as well.

You have two solutions, bump your API version to 16+, or use

[`NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#PRIORITY_HIGH)

Comment: yea,it's set at 10. but what about it? what should i do?

Comment: It was not introduced until 16... So how do you expect to use it in 10? Find another way, or bump your version to 16+.

Comment: @zobrist23 You're *compiling* against API level 10? Holy hell. How? That was new 5 years ago.

Comment: @zobrist23 You *absolutely need to* learn the difference between `compileSdkVersion`,`targetSdkVersion` and `minimumSdkVersion`.